# Which DLL should I reference that contains the Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model namespace types used in the Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am coding in c#. I am trying to call the cmdlets of the Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module from C# but can't create a PasswordProfile parameter for an invocation of New-AzureADUser because it is a type in the Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model namespace. I can't find a DLL to reference that contains that namespace. Can anybody direct me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this namespace is defined in the `Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.Open.AzureADBeta.Graph.Client.dll`. You can find these dll in the specific version of Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module. For example, I installed the Azure AD PowerShell Version 2 preview module(2.0.0.85), then thse library could be found in the path below:

**C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureADPreview\2.0.0.85**

Comment: My installed version is AzureAD 2.0.0.71 so I found the DLL at C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.0.71\Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.Client.dll. Thank you very much for the pointer.

Comment: I just installed the AzureAD module on our build machine and it was version 2.0.0.98, which installed in the C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD folder (note no sub-folder for the version). And it had a breaking change in it. The DeletionTimeStamp property of the User class has been renamed DeletionTimestamp.