# Find .dll of an "external" class showing in debugger in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, powershell, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory

**In short:**

My debugger shows a class called **Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.User**.

How do I find a dll of an "external" class like that one?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which DLL should I reference that contains the Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model namespace types used in the Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053558/which-dll-should-i-reference-that-contains-the-microsoft-open-azuread-model-name)

Comment: I've change my question a bit to ask for the method of finding dll's, and not getting the name the specific dll of the ..Model.User class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the [Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window)  (which is sort of a REPL for debugging) and get the assembly from the type:

```
BaseObject.GetType().Assembly
```

That is:

```
debug.print(Result(0).BaseObject.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase)
```

Output:

```
file:///C:/Program Files/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/AzureAD/2.0.0.115/Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.Client.dll
```