# Set-AzureADUserLicense error when trying to create license object

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a script for adding user licenses to O365. when I run the following line:

```
$license = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I couldn't find anything to address this error and hoping for some help.

Comment: Not familiar with this error but Is the AzureAD Module up to date and was `Import-Module AzureAD` used previously?

Comment: Yes, I had imported the  `Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell` not sure if the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` was an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research that type is part of the AzureAD module, which is also pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053558/which-dll-should-i-reference-that-contains-the-microsoft-open-azuread-model-name). What isn't pointed out is how to utilize the dll. Here's a little bit of code that should bring that namespace into your session and allow your command to work. It also deals with having more than one AzureAD module installed, which can be removed if you are certain you'll only ever have one.

```
Get-Module AzureAD -ListAvailable | Sort-Object Version | Select-Object -Last 1 | ForEach-Object {
    $AzureADGraphDLL = $_.filelist -match '.*graph.*.dll$'
    Import-Module $AzureADGraphDLL
}
```

Demo

```
$license = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses

$license.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     False    AssignedLicenses                         System.Object
```

Comment: My first guess was that he either didn't import the module first or was outdated or didn't have it installed. I couldn't find much info either on MS Docs

Comment: Even with the module imported I got the same error. I had to import one of those dlls.

Comment: Funny that Microsoft is showing us an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserlicense?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1--add-a-license-to-a-user-based-on-a-template-user) of what OP is trying to do yet it never mentions this. As per usual, some MS Docs are poorly documented. Nice finding tho, +1

Comment: Thanks @DougMaurer, this worked!  FYI, used I `Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell` and other AzureAD functions are working in my script. This was the only one not working (so far, lol).

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module -Name 'AzureAD' -UseWindowsPowershell
Import-Module -Name 'AzureAD' -NoClobber
$licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
```

This was tested on PowerShell v7. The current AzureAD module is not compatible with PSv7 and runs in a v5.1 remote session. This allows for the data types to be imported to the script session and run the cmdlets in the remote session.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same error message after making a typo in the -TypeName value:
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicens

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).